# How to set image only for a certain part of title in UIButton

Tags: ios, uiimageview, uibutton, uikit

I have a UIButton that has a title.
Consider it as Thu 20.
There is an image which is set as the background for the button,this image is width resized and content mode is aspect fit.So it appears to the full button.
My problem:
I need the image only for the "20" part and not the entire "Thu 20".
if you see the iPad calendar you will get the point.
How can i do it?
Thanks

Comment: can you add your image here?

Comment: @KathiravanG https://raw.githubusercontent.com/fggeraissate/FFCalendar/master/FFCalendar/FFCalendars/Util/Images/DailyCalendar.png

Comment: Red circle your image right?

Comment: u want red circle to cover only 20 right?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/57996/discussion-between-kathiravan-g-and-vin).

Answer (score 0):

Unless something like an attributed string has a functionality of putting a rectangle around some text I suggest you to create a custom view that handles this:

You would need a view that excepts 2 strings, a normal one and the one in the rectangle. Then insert a normal label, set the text, call sizeToFit. Then add the second label and do the same as first but in the end place it right next to the first label. Then add the image view onto the label respecting the labels dimensions. Then resize the whole view to fit all the views on it. Now you can add this custom label to a button or anywhere you want it...

Answer (score 0):

I would rather suggest you place an Image VIew containing your Image and Then place a Label on top of Image with your "20" over it and then Place a custom UIButton with No backGround Color, and No Images on the top of both

Answer (score 0):

With a bit of work you could override one of these `UIButton` methods to place the image at the correct location. Using a method within `UILabel` to determine the coordinates of "20" would give the the location for the image.

```
class UIButton {

    // these return the rectangle for the background (assumes bounds), the content (image + title) and for the image and title separately. the content rect is calculated based
    // on the title and image size and padding and then adjusted based on the control content alignment. there are no draw methods since the contents
    // are rendered in separate subviews (UIImageView, UILabel)

    open func backgroundRect(forBounds bounds: CGRect) -> CGRect

    open func contentRect(forBounds bounds: CGRect) -> CGRect

    open func titleRect(forContentRect contentRect: CGRect) -> CGRect

    open func imageRect(forContentRect contentRect: CGRect) -> CGRect
}
```

See Apple's [Documentation](https://developer.apple.com/reference/uikit/uibutton#symbols) under "Getting Dimensions" for more information about these methods.